# hover on a <a> element stay block after and alert box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap and I have this navBar :

```js
$('#linkNav').click(function() {
    var r = confirm("Do you really really wanna do that?");
    if (r == false) {
        //randomfunc();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <span class="navbar-brand" disabled>Title</span>>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a id="linkNav" href="#">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Everything work well except one really annoying little thing.

On my link I have a Hover to pass it color to white when the mouse pass over (bootstrap standard navbar) but when I click on the link (so color white) the box open I click on one button (ok or cancel no matter) and the link stay white. But if I click on the page no matter where it return to his original color.

Someone know how to fix this?

Comment: can u add code. Please make it a snippet if u can

Comment: I can't do a snippet because I use bootstrap library (or i don't know how to do). What part of the code do you need more? actualy with just what i give on this post the error is alreaddy here.

Comment: Prateik Darji, why did you edit the question to use references to Bootstrap 3 when the OP specifically tagged Bootstrap 4 in the question?

Comment: sorry my fault i use bootstrap 3 i just don't find bootstrap 3 tag

Comment: @Kvasir Your question has been updated with the twitter-bootstrap-3 tag instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your are going to hack the bootstrap css do it right, i assume you already do that with a tag for nav-bar so lets do the rest

```
.nav-bar > li > a:hover,
.nav-bar > li > a:focus{
   color: white; //<<the one you want
   background-color: black; //the one you want
}
```

maybe you need to add !important to those properties to work properly

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Bootstrap will add an **`active`** **class** to the menu item (to either that `li` or `a` element,which I am not sure).

So, do remove that class within the **click** ***event handler*** function.

Hope this would help.....

Comment: I check with my consol (chrome and firefox) and their is no class added. Actualy in the debug the color is indicate as grey ... but it's not (until i click somewhere)

Comment: No, I am very sure a class will be added in Bootstrap.....

Or else check the pseudo classes being applied on those elements. (You can do this by selecting the `a` in inspect element and selecting pseudo-classes in **:hov** of chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the selector :active or some combinations with :focus.

```
#linknav:active {
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , and import jquery js in project.

```
$( "#linkNav" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```